How to use match_template from the opencv Rust package to find the coordinates of an image inside another image?
I have the following: image and I would like to get the coordinates of this smaller part of the image.
I tried to create this utility function:
use image::EncodableLayout;
use opencv::{
    core::{min_max_loc, Point},
    imgcodecs::{imdecode, imread, IMREAD_UNCHANGED},
    imgproc::{match_template, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED},
    prelude::*,
};

const MIN_ACCURACY: f64 = 0.8;

pub fn get_image_coordinates(image_file_name: &str, template: Vec<u8>) -> Option<Vec<i32>> {
    // haystack is the small image
    let haystack = imread(
        &format!("assets/images/{image_file_name}.png"),
        IMREAD_UNCHANGED,
    )
    .unwrap();

    // needle is the large image
    let needle = imdecode(&template.as_bytes(), IMREAD_UNCHANGED).unwrap();

    let mut result = Mat::default();
    let mask = Mat::default();

    match_template(&haystack, &needle, &mut result, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, &mask).unwrap();

    let mut min_val: f64 = 0.0;
    let mut max_val: f64 = 0.0;
    let mut min_loc = Point::new(0, 0);
    let mut max_loc = Point::new(0, 0);

    min_max_loc(
        &result,
        Some(&mut min_val),
        Some(&mut max_val),
        Some(&mut min_loc),
        Some(&mut max_loc),
        &mask,
    )
    .unwrap();

    println!("max val: {}", max_val);

    if max_val > MIN_ACCURACY {
        Some(vec![max_loc.x, max_loc.y])
    } else {
        None
    }
}

However this call to match_template results in:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { code: "StsAssert, -215", message: "OpenCV(4.10.0) C:\\GHA-OCV-1\\_work\\ci-gha-workflow\\ci-gha-workflow\\opencv\\modules\\imgproc\\src\\templmatch.cpp:1164: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2 in function 'cv::matchTemplate'\n" }

I would not expect this to fail since both haystack.depth() and needle.depth() give me 0 which represents CV_8U. When match_template succeeds, I would expect a value above 0 for max_val.

is this a Rust problem, or a computer vision problem? [mre] it's on you to figure you which it is, and to simplify. -- are you for real? that first picture is a mess. I can't even tell what it is.

Is it relevant to the question?

you have two tags on your question: rust and opencv. if you ask the rust people, they don't know about computer vision. if you ask the opencv people, they don't know about rust. both tags have a finite number of regulars. this is not a numbers game where you can hope for someone to eventually find their caring streak and help you without your cooperation. you benefit from making it easy for people to help you. [ask]

alright, I spotted the instance of the template. at least it looks unaffected. so there's a chance. -- as to the assertion: (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) && type == _templ.type() && _img.dims() <= 2. investigate each clause of this and how it relates to the arguments you gave the call. -- IMREAD_UNCHANGED is a good candidate for causing trouble, if you don't know the file's format. -- and TM_CCOEFF_NORMED is going to bite you in the ass too. it always does. yet everyone tries that damned mode.

in short: you might want to check the number of channels of both Mat arguments

there's been a bunch of the same advice on that same assertion: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=(depth+%3D%3D+CV_8U+%7C%7C+depth+%3D%3D+CV_32F)+%26%26+type+%3D%3D+_templ.type()+%26%26+_img.dims()+%3C%3D+2+in+function+%27cv%3A%3AmatchTemplate%27

I managed to solve it using IMREAD_COLOR instead, although I am not sure why IMREAD_UNCHANGED was causing trouble since both file formats are PNG

check the number of channels

haystack gave me 2 channels and needle 4
